# How to calculate the different combinations of an NxM grid with 3-valid values

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

I have 3 valid values: a,b,c
I can insert them in a Nx3 grid in such a way that no row or column contains cells that are the same values. How can I calculate the number of valid patterns that can be created using N rows?

For example, if N = 4, the total number of valid pattern is 296490.
[image]

This is my attempt:

```
def countPatterns(n):

    dp1, dp2 = 6,6
    mod = 10 ** 9 + 7
    
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        dp1, dp2 = (dp1 * 3 + dp2 * 2) % mod, (dp1 * 2 + dp2 * 2) % mod
    return (dp1 + dp2) % mod
```

When N = 4, the output should be 174 but I'm getting 54.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved using standard techniques from combinatorics.

```
import math


# Counts the number of grids where the first i rows and first j columns are
# monochrome. All of the monochrome rows and columns must have the same color if
# and only if both i and j are nonzero. Otherwise, the color choices are
# independent.
def count_monochrome(n, i, m, j):
    return 3 ** (1 if i and j else i + j) * 3 ** ((n - i) * (m - j))


# Uses inclusion-exclusion to count the number of grids with no monochrome row
# or column.
def count(n, m=3):
    # There are math.comb(n, i) * math.comb(m, j) intersections with i
    # monochrome rows and j monochrome columns.
    return sum(
        math.comb(n, i)
        * math.comb(m, j)
        * (-1) ** (i + j)
        * count_monochrome(n, i, m, j)
        for i in range(n + 1)
        for j in range(m + 1)
    ) % (10 ** 9 + 7)


print(count(4))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer

This can also be solved mathematically and so the formula is:

24<sup>n</sup> - (9 * 8<sup>n</sup> - 9 * 2<sup>n</sup> - 18 * 3<sup>n</sup> + 24)

```
def countPatterns(n):
    result = 24**n - (9 * 8**n - 9*2**n - 18*3**n + 24)
    mod = 10 ** 9 + 7
    return result % mod

print (countPatterns(4))
```

> 296490

## Long Answer

## 1. Condition : no row contains same values

For a given row, there are `3` ways to set a colour in each cell. So, there are 3<sup>3</sup>=27 possible combinations. However, out of these `27` combinations, `3` are `GGG`, `BBB` and `RRR`. So, they have to be excluded and the number of valid combinations in a row is `27 - 3 = 24`.

Hence, the total number of combinations for a table with n rows is 24<sup>n</sup>

## 2. Condition : no column contains same values

To solve this case, we can count all "invalid combinations" and then subtract their number from the total number (which is 24<sup>n</sup> as stated in the previous section).

### 2.1 Invalid combinations

1. Only first column has same values.
2. Only second column has same values.
3. Only third column has same values.
4. Only 2 first columns have same values (value from the first column is not necessarily equal to the other one).
5. Only 2 last columns have same values.
6. Only first and last columns have same values.
7. Values within each column are equal.

Obviously, number of combinations for `1` is equal to `2` and `3`. The same can be noted about `4`, `5` and `6`.

If we sum up combinations from `1` to `7`, then we'll get the total number.

However, it's hard to calculate (1)-(7) individually, but easier to calculate the number of combinations such that at least `k` columns have the same values. Once those are found, we will apply an [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to find the number of combinations asked in the question.

#### 2.1.1 First column has same values

For each row, there are `8` combinations such that the row starts with `R`:

```
RRG
RRB
RGR
RGG
RGB
RBR
RBG
RBB
```

That means that for a table with `n`, there are 8<sup>n</sup> combinations in which first column consists of `8`s. Thereof, there are 3*8<sup>n</sup> combinations such that the first column starts from `R`, `G` or `B`.

Now, it's important to realise that this number represents `4` invalid cases - `1`, `4`, `6` and `7` (all sets of columns containing the first column).

#### 2.1.2 Second column has same values

Basically, we can use the same logic as above to realise that it's also 3*8<sup>n</sup>.

This represents `2`, `4`, `5` and `7`.

#### 2.1.3 Third column has same values

Same as before - 3*8<sup>n</sup>.

This covers `3`, `5`, `6` and `7`.

If we add up combinations from these `3` steps, we will get **9*8<sup>n</sup>**. However, as noted in those steps, we will count `4`, `5` and `6` twice. `7` will be counted thrice.

#### 2.1.4 2 columns have same values

Let's count it for `2` first columns because the number for every pair of columns is still the same.

If a row starts with `2` identical colours, then there are `2` combinations for each colour. If not, then there are `3` combinations for each pair (there are `6` possible pairs). Hence, the total number of combinations is **3 * 2<sup>n</sup> + 6 * 3<sup>n</sup>**.

So, the number of combinations for `4` and `7` is 3 * 2<sup>n</sup> + 6 * 3<sup>n</sup>.

The number of combinations for `5` and `7` is 3 * 2<sup>n</sup> + 6 * 3<sup>n</sup>.

The number of combinations for `6` and `7` is 3 * 2<sup>n</sup> + 6 * 3<sup>n</sup>.

#### 2.1.5 Values within each column equal

This means that all rows must be equal. As there are only `24` ways to construct a row, there are `24` ways to have all values equal within columns. So, it's **24**.

### Total number of invalid cases

As said before, if we sum up *2.1.1*, *2.1.2* and *2.1.3*, then we will count `4`, `5` and `6` twice, `7` - `3` times (from **2.1**). Since the number of combinations for each pair of columns is the same, we can just subtract **3 * 2<sup>n</sup> + 6 * 2<sup>n</sup>** `3` times (from 2.1.4), and then add the number of combinations for a three column case once (because it won't be there after the subtraction).

9 * 8<sup>n</sup> - 3 * (3 * 2<sup>n</sup> + 6 * 3<sup>n</sup>) + 24 = 9 * 8<sup>n</sup> - 9 * 2<sup>n</sup> - 18 * 3<sup>n</sup> + 24

## 3. Final Answer

Now, just subtract the number of invalid cases from 24<sup>n</sup>:

24<sup>n</sup> - (9 * 8<sup>n</sup> - 9 * 2<sup>n</sup> - 18 * 3<sup>n</sup> + 24)

Don't forget to apply a modulo operation by 10<sup>9</sup> + 7 at the end.